# Hadoop command fails with python3 & works with python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, hadoop, mrjob

I have a macbook pro & i have installed hadoop 2.7.3 on it following this :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=06hpB_Rfv-w

I am trying to run hadoop MRJob command via python3 & it is giving me this error:.

```
bhoots21304s-MacBook-Pro:2.7.3 bhoots21304$ python3 /Users/bhoots21304/PycharmProjects/untitled/MRJobs/Mr_Jobs.py -r hadoop /Users/bhoots21304/PycharmProjects/untitled/MRJobs/File.txt
No configs found; falling back on auto-configuration
Looking for hadoop binary in /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/bin...
Found hadoop binary: /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/bin/hadoop
Using Hadoop version 2.7.3
Looking for Hadoop streaming jar in /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3...
Found Hadoop streaming jar: /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/libexec/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.7.3.jar
Creating temp directory /var/folders/53/lvdfwyr52m1gbyf236xv3x1h0000gn/T/Mr_Jobs.bhoots21304.20170328.165022.965610
Copying local files to hdfs:///user/bhoots21304/tmp/mrjob/Mr_Jobs.bhoots21304.20170328.165022.965610/files/...
Running step 1 of 1...
  Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
  packageJobJar: [/var/folders/53/lvdfwyr52m1gbyf236xv3x1h0000gn/T/hadoop-unjar5078580082326840824/] [] /var/folders/53/lvdfwyr52m1gbyf236xv3x1h0000gn/T/streamjob2711596457025539343.jar tmpDir=null
  Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
  Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
  Total input paths to process : 1
  number of splits:2
  Submitting tokens for job: job_1490719699504_0003
  Submitted application application_1490719699504_0003
  The url to track the job: http://bhoots21304s-MacBook-Pro.local:8088/proxy/application_1490719699504_0003/
  Running job: job_1490719699504_0003
  Job job_1490719699504_0003 running in uber mode : false
   map 0% reduce 0%
  Task Id : attempt_1490719699504_0003_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143

  Task Id : attempt_1490719699504_0003_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

  Task Id : attempt_1490719699504_0003_m_000001_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143

  Task Id : attempt_1490719699504_0003_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

  Task Id : attempt_1490719699504_0003_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

  Task Id : attempt_1490719699504_0003_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

   map 100% reduce 100%
  Job job_1490719699504_0003 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1490719699504_0003_m_000001
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

  Job not successful!
  Streaming Command Failed!
Counters: 17
    Job Counters 
        Data-local map tasks=2
        Failed map tasks=7
        Killed map tasks=1
        Killed reduce tasks=1
        Launched map tasks=8
        Other local map tasks=6
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=18991104
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=0
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=18546
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=18546
        Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=18546
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=0
    Map-Reduce Framework
        CPU time spent (ms)=0
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
Scanning logs for probable cause of failure...
Looking for history log in hdfs:///tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging...
STDERR: 17/03/28 22:21:04 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
STDERR: ls: `hdfs:///user/bhoots21304/tmp/mrjob/Mr_Jobs.bhoots21304.20170328.165022.965610/output/_logs': No such file or directory
STDERR: 17/03/28 22:21:06 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
STDERR: ls: `hdfs:///tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/userlogs/application_1490719699504_0003': No such file or directory
STDERR: 17/03/28 22:21:07 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
STDERR: ls: `hdfs:///user/bhoots21304/tmp/mrjob/Mr_Jobs.bhoots21304.20170328.165022.965610/output/_logs/userlogs/application_1490719699504_0003': No such file or directory
Probable cause of failure:

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

Step 1 of 1 failed: Command '['/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/bin/hadoop', 'jar', '/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/libexec/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.7.3.jar', '-files', 'hdfs:///user/bhoots21304/tmp/mrjob/Mr_Jobs.bhoots21304.20170328.165022.965610/files/Mr_Jobs.py#Mr_Jobs.py,hdfs:///user/bhoots21304/tmp/mrjob/Mr_Jobs.bhoots21304.20170328.165022.965610/files/mrjob.zip#mrjob.zip,hdfs:///user/bhoots21304/tmp/mrjob/Mr_Jobs.bhoots21304.20170328.165022.965610/files/setup-wrapper.sh#setup-wrapper.sh', '-input', 'hdfs:///user/bhoots21304/tmp/mrjob/Mr_Jobs.bhoots21304.20170328.165022.965610/files/File.txt', '-output', 'hdfs:///user/bhoots21304/tmp/mrjob/Mr_Jobs.bhoots21304.20170328.165022.965610/output', '-mapper', 'sh -ex setup-wrapper.sh python3 Mr_Jobs.py --step-num=0 --mapper', '-reducer', 'sh -ex setup-wrapper.sh python3 Mr_Jobs.py --step-num=0 --reducer']' returned non-zero exit status 256.
```

Problem is if i run the same command with python2.7 then it runs fine & shows me the correct output.

Python3 is added in bash_profile.

export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 2.6
PATH="/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
PATH="/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# added by Anaconda2 4.2.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/bhoots21304/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3
export PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$PATH

export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/hive/2.1.0/libexec
export PATH=$HIVE_HOME:$PATH

export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/libexec/share/hadoop/common 
export PATH=$HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR:$PATH

export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/libexec/share/hadoop"
export PATH=$HADOOP_OPTS:$PATH

export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/bin"

# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

This is my MR_Jobs.py:

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
import re

WORD_RE = re.compile(r"[\w']+")


class MRWordFreqCount(MRJob):

    def mapper(self, _, line):
        for word in WORD_RE.findall(line):
            yield (word.lower(), 1)

    def combiner(self, word, counts):
        yield (word, sum(counts))

    def reducer(self, word, counts):
        yield (word, sum(counts))


if __name__ == '__main__':
     MRWordFreqCount.run()
```

&&

I am running it on hadoop using this command:

python3 /Users/bhoots21304/PycharmProjects/untitled/MRJobs/Mr_Jobs.py -r hadoop /Users/bhoots21304/PycharmProjects/untitled/MRJobs/File.txt

If i run the same file using the above mentioned command on my ubuntu machine..it works but when i run the same thing on my mac machine it gives me an error.

Here are the logs from my mac machine :

```
2017-03-28 23:05:51,751 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2017-03-28 23:05:51,863 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2017-03-28 23:05:51,965 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2017-03-28 23:05:51,965 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: MapTask metrics system started
2017-03-28 23:05:51,976 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Executing with tokens:
2017-03-28 23:05:51,976 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Kind: mapreduce.job, Service: job_1490719699504_0005, Ident: (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.token.JobTokenIdentifier@209da20d)
2017-03-28 23:05:52,254 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Sleeping for 0ms before retrying again. Got null now.
2017-03-28 23:05:52,632 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping MapTask metrics system...
2017-03-28 23:05:52,632 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: MapTask metrics system stopped.
2017-03-28 23:05:52,632 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: MapTask metrics system shutdown complete.

+ __mrjob_PWD=/tmp/nm-local-
dir/usercache/bhoots21304/appcache/application_1490719699504_0005/ 
container_1490719699504_0005_01_000010
+ exec
+ python3 -c 'import fcntl; fcntl.flock(9, fcntl.LOCK_EX)'
setup-wrapper.sh: line 6: python3: command not found


2017-03-28 23:05:47,691 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2017-03-28 23:05:47,802 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2017-03-28 23:05:47,879 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2017-03-28 23:05:47,879 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: MapTask metrics system started
2017-03-28 23:05:47,889 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Executing with tokens:
2017-03-28 23:05:47,889 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Kind: mapreduce.job, Service: job_1490719699504_0005, Ident: (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.token.JobTokenIdentifier@209da20d)
2017-03-28 23:05:48,079 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Sleeping for 0ms before retrying again. Got null now.
2017-03-28 23:05:48,316 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: mapreduce.cluster.local.dir for child: /tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/bhoots21304/appcache/application_1490719699504_0005
2017-03-28 23:05:48,498 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
2017-03-28 23:05:48,805 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
2017-03-28 23:05:48,810 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree: ProcfsBasedProcessTree currently is supported only on Linux.
2017-03-28 23:05:48,810 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : null
2017-03-28 23:05:48,908 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/bhoots21304/tmp/mrjob/Mr_Jobs.bhoots21304.20170328.173517.724664/files/File.txt:0+32
2017-03-28 23:05:48,923 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 1
2017-03-28 23:05:48,983 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
2017-03-28 23:05:48,984 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
2017-03-28 23:05:48,984 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 83886080
2017-03-28 23:05:48,984 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
2017-03-28 23:05:48,984 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
2017-03-28 23:05:48,989 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
2017-03-28 23:05:49,001 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: PipeMapRed exec [/bin/sh, -ex, setup-wrapper.sh, python3, Mr_Jobs.py, --step-num=0, --mapper]
2017-03-28 23:05:49,010 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: mapred.work.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.output.dir
2017-03-28 23:05:49,010 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: map.input.start is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.input.start
2017-03-28 23:05:49,011 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: job.local.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.local.dir
2017-03-28 23:05:49,011 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: mapred.task.is.map is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.ismap
2017-03-28 23:05:49,011 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: mapred.task.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.attempt.id
2017-03-28 23:05:49,011 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: mapred.tip.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.id
2017-03-28 23:05:49,011 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: mapred.local.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.cluster.local.dir
2017-03-28 23:05:49,012 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: map.input.file is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.input.file
2017-03-28 23:05:49,012 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: mapred.skip.on is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.skiprecords
2017-03-28 23:05:49,012 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: map.input.length is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.input.length
2017-03-28 23:05:49,012 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: mapred.cache.localFiles is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.cache.local.files
2017-03-28 23:05:49,012 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.id
2017-03-28 23:05:49,013 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: mapred.task.partition is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.partition
2017-03-28 23:05:49,025 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: R/W/S=1/0/0 in:NA [rec/s] out:NA [rec/s]
2017-03-28 23:05:49,026 INFO [Thread-14] org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: MRErrorThread done
2017-03-28 23:05:49,027 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: PipeMapRed failed!
java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
2017-03-28 23:05:49,028 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Exception running child : java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

2017-03-28 23:05:49,031 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Runnning cleanup for the task
2017-03-28 23:05:49,035 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter: Could not delete hdfs://localhost:9000/user/bhoots21304/tmp/mrjob/Mr_Jobs.bhoots21304.20170328.173517.724664/output/_temporary/1/_temporary/attempt_1490719699504_0005_m_000000_2
2017-03-28 23:05:49,140 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping MapTask metrics system...
2017-03-28 23:05:49,141 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: MapTask metrics system stopped.
2017-03-28 23:05:49,141 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: MapTask metrics system shutdown complete.

Mar 28, 2017 11:05:33 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.JAXBContextResolver as a provider class
Mar 28, 2017 11:05:33 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler as a provider class
Mar 28, 2017 11:05:33 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.AMWebServices as a root resource class
Mar 28, 2017 11:05:33 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
Mar 28, 2017 11:05:33 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.JAXBContextResolver to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton"
Mar 28, 2017 11:05:34 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton"
Mar 28, 2017 11:05:34 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.AMWebServices to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Comment: could your post your task logs? location of this logs is set by yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs property

Comment: hi, there is no yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs property in my yarn-site.xml..where else can i find the location of task logs?

Comment: Show us what is inside `MR_Jobs.py`. Are you using a python2 code with python3?

Comment: in cloudera default path for logs is /var/log/hadoop-yarn/container, it also can be set by YARN_LOG_DIR variable in in yarn-env.sh

Comment: @franklinsijo I have added Mr_Jobs.py to my question..yes i am using python2 code with python3..that shouldn't be an issue because when i run the same thing in my ubuntu machine..it works..in mac it shows an error..

Comment: @fi11er i have posted all the distinct logs..I am using Hadoop on my mac machine installed locally..I am not using the sandbox provided by cloudera/hortonworks..in mac I am able to find logs..but for 1 run there are several container folders created and inside each container folder there are stderr file & a log file..

Comment: that's right, each task is running in its own container and writing to a specific folder. In logs that you added you can see `setup-wrapper.sh: line 6: python3: command not found` that means that python3 is not in your PATH. probably your task is running as another user, or you added python3 to the path after you started Hadoop server.

Comment: @fi11er  python3 is now added to my bash_profile..i have also updated it above in my question..but it is still showing me the same error. what do u mean by "probably your task is running as another user"?

Comment: I mean that command  `python3 -c 'import fcntl; fcntl.flock(9, fcntl.LOCK_EX)'` is run by nodemanager, so I have 2 ideas what is wrong:
1) you added python3 to the path of your user, but node manager is run by another, so there are no python3 in its path.
2) you added python3 to the path after nodemanager is started, so it can't see this change. Try to restart cluster

Comment: @fi11er I tried restarting the cluster..it still didn't work..since I have only 1 user in mac it  rules out the possibility of idea #1..also in my mac python is present at 2 paths..#1 is at "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin" && #2 is at "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/bin"..so which path should i give in bash_profile & bash_profile.pysave? #1 was installed from .pkg file which I downoaded from python.org && #2 was installed via homebrew..

Comment: Well /usr/local looks like a more canonical path. You can type `which python3` to see its path.

Comment: @fi11er  i have added /usr/local path in bash_profile and it is still showing me the same error..help..what should i do now?

Comment: This is really strange, can you try to run some simple hadoop streaming job without mrjob?

Comment: @fi11er just now I tried to run a hadoop streaming job(without MRJob) with python3..it did not work..tried again with python..it worked..

Comment: run in streaming job shell-script with `echo $PATH` to see the actual path.

Comment: @fi11er i didnt understand u..i am running streaming via this command :  bin/hadoop \
   jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.7.3.jar \
   -mapper "python3 /home/bhoots21304/Desktop/mapper.py" \
   -reducer "python3 /home/bhoots21304/Desktop/reducer.py" \
   -input "/input/file.txt" \
   -output "wordcount"                                                                                                now where do i give echo $PATH in this?
please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @fi11er Reason 1:
i think python3 is not mentioned in "/usr/bin/env". i can't edit env file bcoz it's a unix executable file. so how do i add python3 path in it.

Reason 2:
python3 (alias file as well as an executable file) is not present in /usr/bin..while python(unix executable) , python2.6(alias file) , python2.7(alias file) are present..maybe thats why it works with "python/python2.7" command and not with "python3" command..what can be the solution to this?

Comment: u can run `bin/hadoop \ jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.‌​7.3.jar \ -mapper 'echo $PATH' \ -input "/input/file.txt" \ -output "wordcount"` and in output hdfs directory u will see PATH which is used when running mapper

Comment: and try to put a symlink to python3 to /usr/bin, maybe this can help

Comment: @fi11er hi, I finally ran it with the following command:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3 /Users/bhoots21304/PycharmProjects/untitled/Netflix/Top_ten_most_viewed_movies.py -r hadoop /Users/bhoots21304/Documents/Netflix/training_set --python-bin /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3

& it worked..

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a `~/.mrjob.conf` file with this content:

```
runners:
  hadoop:
    python_bin: /usr/local/bin/python3
    hadoop_bin: /usr/local/opt/hadoop/bin/hadoop
    hadoop_streaming_jar: /usr/local/opt/hadoop/libexec/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-*.jar
```

Then run your program with this command:

```
python3 your_program.py -r hadoop input.txt
```